# Truncate a string to first n characters of a string and add three dots if any characters are removed

Tags: php, string, ellipsis, truncation

How can I get the first n characters of a string in PHP? What's the fastest way to trim a string to a specific number of characters, and append '...' if needed?

Comment: might be better to use the ellipsis character  …

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/print-first-80-characters-in-line.html

Comment: Try This Link, May help You...
  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Comment: Here is a good comparison of multiple techniques: [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354552/2943403).

Comment: Please indicate if you are going to handle multi-byte strings like at least one letter with an accent like `à` etc.  I know that this is an old question but that would clarify how people should consolidate the answers here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 676, accepted):

```
//The simple version for 10 Characters from the beginning of the string
$string = substr($string,0,10).'...';
```

Update:

Based on suggestion for checking length (and also ensuring similar lengths on trimmed and untrimmed strings):

```
$string = (strlen($string) > 13) ? substr($string,0,10).'...' : $string;
```

So you will get a string of max 13 characters; either 13 (or less) normal characters or 10 characters followed by '...'

Update 2:

Or as function:

```
function truncate($string, $length, $dots = "...") {
    return (strlen($string) > $length) ? substr($string, 0, $length - strlen($dots)) . $dots : $string;
}
```

Update 3:

It's been a while since I wrote this answer and I don't actually use this code any more. I prefer this function which prevents breaking the string in the middle of a word using the `wordwrap` function:

```
function truncate($string,$length=100,$append="&hellip;") {
  $string = trim($string);

  if(strlen($string) > $length) {
    $string = wordwrap($string, $length);
    $string = explode("\n", $string, 2);
    $string = $string[0] . $append;
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Comment: might be best to replace with ellipsis ( … ) rather than 3 dots ( ... )

Comment: I love this, but I changed it and use the following to remove whitespace at the end:
$string = substr(trim($string),0,10).'...';
That way you get something like "I like to..." instead of "I like to ...".

Comment: "hellip" - took me sometime to understand we were not talking about satan's ip adress

Comment: In case there is a hard cap on the length of the returned string, shouldn't line 5 of update 3 be `$string = wordwrap($string, $length - sizeof($append));`  ?

Comment: is this multibyte safe?

Comment: No @TimoHuovinen - this is not multibyte safe. And should be declared in the answer but the edit queue is full now, as usual to me.

Answer (score 159):

This functionality has been built into PHP since version 4.0.6. [See the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php).

```
echo mb_strimwidth('Hello World', 0, 10, '...');

// outputs Hello W...
```

Note that the `trimmarker` (the ellipsis above) are included in the truncated length.

Comment: WARNING: mb_strimwidth() requires the Multibyte String extension to be installed and activated and that's not always the case so test before deploying.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, be careful with mb_strimwidth(), as a string's *length* (number of characters it contains) may not be the same as its *width*: CJK chars can be half- or full-width. Example:
plain ascii `ab: bytes=2, chars=2, width=2`, western unicode `éö: bytes=4, chars=2, width=2`, katakana [Wo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wo_(kana)), half and full width) `ｦヲ: bytes=6, chars=2, width=3`

Comment: We should probably mention in an explicit way in the answer that this is multibyte safe. So this is the only correct solution to handle wild user input. Indeed it's not the solution if you are interested in handling binary strings. But the question is a bit vague now. I cannot clarify this right now since the edit queue is full now, as usual to me.

Answer (score 15):

The Multibyte extension can come in handy if you need control over the string charset.

```
$charset = 'UTF-8';
$length = 10;
$string = 'Hai to yoo! I like yoo soo!';
if(mb_strlen($string, $charset) > $length) {
  $string = mb_substr($string, 0, $length - 3, $charset) . '...';
}
```

Comment: This code is adding the three dots to the string? my code it has a link tag <a> and when I link it it will link it together with the three dots which it will come as a different value.

Answer (score 11):

sometimes, you need to limit the string to the last complete word ie: you don't want the last word to be broken instead you stop with the second last word.

eg: 
we need to limit "This is my String" to 6 chars but instead of 'This i..." we want it to be 'This..."  ie we will skip that broken letters in the last word.

phew, am bad at explaining, here is the code.

```
class Fun {

    public function limit_text($text, $len) {
        if (strlen($text) < $len) {
            return $text;
        }
        $text_words = explode(' ', $text);
        $out = null;


        foreach ($text_words as $word) {
            if ((strlen($word) > $len) && $out == null) {

                return substr($word, 0, $len) . "...";
            }
            if ((strlen($out) + strlen($word)) > $len) {
                return $out . "...";
            }
            $out.=" " . $word;
        }
        return $out;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to cut being careful to don't split words you can do the following

```
function ellipse($str,$n_chars,$crop_str=' [...]')
{
    $buff=strip_tags($str);
    if(strlen($buff) > $n_chars)
    {
        $cut_index=strpos($buff,' ',$n_chars);
        $buff=substr($buff,0,($cut_index===false? $n_chars: $cut_index+1)).$crop_str;
    }
    return $buff;
}
```

if $str is shorter than $n_chars returns it untouched.

If $str is equal to $n_chars returns it as is as well.

if $str is longer than $n_chars then it looks for the next space to cut or (if no more spaces till the end) $str gets cut rudely instead at $n_chars.

**NOTE:** be aware that this method will remove all tags in case of HTML.

Answer (score 8):

The codeigniter framework contains a helper for this, called the "text helper". Here's some documentation from codeigniter's user guide that applies: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html
(just read the word_limiter and character_limiter sections).
Here's two functions from it relevant to your question:

```
if ( ! function_exists('word_limiter'))
{
    function word_limiter($str, $limit = 100, $end_char = '&#8230;')
    {
        if (trim($str) == '')
        {
            return $str;
        }

        preg_match('/^\s*+(?:\S++\s*+){1,'.(int) $limit.'}/', $str, $matches);

        if (strlen($str) == strlen($matches[0]))
        {
            $end_char = '';
        }

        return rtrim($matches[0]).$end_char;
    }
}
```

And

```
if ( ! function_exists('character_limiter'))
{
    function character_limiter($str, $n = 500, $end_char = '&#8230;')
    {
        if (strlen($str) < $n)
        {
            return $str;
        }

        $str = preg_replace("/\s+/", ' ', str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), ' ', $str));

        if (strlen($str) <= $n)
        {
            return $str;
        }

        $out = "";
        foreach (explode(' ', trim($str)) as $val)
        {
            $out .= $val.' ';

            if (strlen($out) >= $n)
            {
                $out = trim($out);
                return (strlen($out) == strlen($str)) ? $out : $out.$end_char;
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(strlen($text) > 10)
     $text = substr($text,0,10) . "...";
```

Comment: From @Brendon Bullen above .. $string = (strlen($string) > 13) ? substr($string,0,10).'...' : $string;   Nice !

Comment: This question is correct for binary strings but it's not correct for multibyte strings. The question is a bit vague over its need, so, better to clarify in an explicit way. Unfortunately the edit queue is full now, as usual to me.

Answer (score 3):

Use substring

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$foo = substr("abcde",0, 3) . "...";
```

Comment: This code will always add ... to the string, which he didn't want.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I edited the answer accordingly. (Revised answer currently awaiting SO peer review)

Comment: This answer is not multibyte safe. That is probably OK (since the question does not clarify this need) but better to be declared in the question itself. I cannot add this information since the edit queue is full, as usual to me.

Comment: @ChayaCooper your edit was refused by somebody, and the reason is: you probably need to write an if, to then decide whenever to append the `...`. Instead in your edit you just removed the `...`. - See the question. I cannot propose a counter-patch now because the edit queue is full now, as usual to me.

Answer (score 3):

It already has a helper method for it in Laravel 6+ versions. You could simply use that.

```
\Str::limit('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 20);
```

which gives you output like

```
The quick brown fox...
```

For more detail please check laravel official document: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-limit

Answer (score 2):

This function do the job without breaking words in the middle

```
    function str_trim($str,$char_no){
        if(strlen($str)<=$char_no)
            return $str;
        else{
            $all_words=explode(" ",$str);
            $out_str='';
            foreach ($all_words as $word) {
                $temp_str=($out_str=='')?$word:$out_str.' '.$word;
                if(strlen($temp_str)>$char_no-3)//-3 for 3 dots
                    return $out_str."...";
                $out_str=$temp_str;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best to abstract you're code like so (notice the limit is optional and defaults to 10):

```
print limit($string);


function limit($var, $limit=10)
{
    if ( strlen($var) > $limit )
    {
        return substr($string, 0, $limit) . '...';
    }
    else
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could explain why this approach is best instead of just asserting that it is?

Comment: @Robert it's simple, and abstracting means you don't have to retype the code over and over.  And most importantly, if you do find a better way to do this, or want something more complex, you only change this 1 function instead of 50 pieces of code.

Comment: Fix: substr of $var, not $string. Test against `$limit + 3` so that you don't trim a string _just_ over the limit. Depending on your application (e.g., HTML output), consider using an entity `&hellip;` instead (typographically more pleasing). As suggested earlier, trim off any non-letters from the end of the (shortened) string before appending the ellipsis. Finally, watch out if you're in a multibyte (e.g., UTF-8) environment -- you can't use strlen() and substr().

Answer (score 1):

The function I used:

```
function cutAfter($string, $len = 30, $append = '...') {
        return (strlen($string) > $len) ? 
          substr($string, 0, $len - strlen($append)) . $append : 
          $string;
}
```

See it [in action](http://codepad.org/HOvZXxVP).

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a function for this use

```
 function str_short($string,$limit)
        {
            $len=strlen($string);
            if($len>$limit)
            {
             $to_sub=$len-$limit;
             $crop_temp=substr($string,0,-$to_sub);
             return $crop_len=$crop_temp."...";
            }
            else
            {
                return $string;
            }
        }
```

you just call the function with string and limite
eg:`str_short("hahahahahah",5)`;
it will cut of your string and add "..." at the end
 :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do

```
    function cutat($num, $tt){
        if (mb_strlen($tt)>$num){
            $tt=mb_substr($tt,0,$num-2).'...';
        }
        return $tt;
    }
```

where $num stands for number of chars, and $tt the string for manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

To create within a function (for repeat usage) and dynamical limited length, use:

```
function string_length_cutoff($string, $limit, $subtext = '...')
{
    return (strlen($string) > $limit) ? substr($string, 0, ($limit-strlen(subtext))).$subtext : $string;
}

// example usage:
echo string_length_cutoff('Michelle Lee Hammontree-Garcia', 26);

// or (for custom substitution text
echo string_length_cutoff('Michelle Lee Hammontree-Garcia', 26, '..');
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the fastest solution, but it looks like it is the shortest one:

```
$result = current(explode("\n", wordwrap($str, $width, "...\n")));
```

P.S. See some examples here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852480/131337

Comment: Thanks but indeed this is an inefficient solution since it calls two parsing functions at least O(N) plus another function, and, unfortunately this is not readable without a comment. Comment that, indeed should be added, to explain this snippet to other people, and so, making this solution not that short :) So probably maybe to have a solution that is a bit longer, but a bit more efficient and/or at least more readable. Also, note that this solution is not multibyte safe and should be declared in the answer, since the question is a bit vague about what they want (but edit queue is full now)

Comment: Premising that this kind of answers could be very interesting in Code Golf - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ValerioBozz Thanks for the constructive criticism. I agree with your concerns regarding that code snippet. Indeed, seven years after I wrote this, I had to refer to the question of this thread to understand what it does! I'll leave my answer as it is to let other people learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Don't say "mistake" :) It works so it's not a mistake. It's just very creative :) eheh

Answer (score 0):

substr() would be best, you'll also want to check the length of the string first

```
$str = 'someLongString';
$max = 7;

if(strlen($str) > $max) {
   $str = substr($str, 0, $max) . '...';
}
```

wordwrap won't trim the string down, just split it up...

Answer (score 0):

$width = 10;

```
$a = preg_replace ("~^(.{{$width}})(.+)~", '\\1…', $a);
```

or with wordwrap

```
$a = preg_replace ("~^(.{1,${width}}\b)(.+)~", '\\1…', $a);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

this solution will not cut words, it will add three dots after the first space.
I edited @Raccoon29 solution and I replaced all functions with **mb_** functions so that this will work for all languages such as arabic

```
function cut_string($str, $n_chars, $crop_str = '...') {
    $buff = strip_tags($str);
    if (mb_strlen($buff) > $n_chars) {
        $cut_index = mb_strpos($buff, ' ', $n_chars);
        $buff = mb_substr($buff, 0, ($cut_index === false ? $n_chars : $cut_index + 1), "UTF-8") . $crop_str;
    }
    return $buff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourString = "bla blaaa bla blllla bla bla";
$out = "";
if(strlen($yourString) > 22) {
    while(strlen($yourString) > 22) {
        $pos = strrpos($yourString, " ");
        if($pos !== false && $pos <= 22) {
            $out = substr($yourString,0,$pos);
            break;
        } else {
            $yourString = substr($yourString,0,$pos);
            continue;
        }
    }
} else {
    $out = $yourString;
}
echo "Output String: ".$out;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no hard requirement on the length of the truncated string, one can use this to truncate and prevent cutting the last word as well:

```
$text = "Knowledge is a natural right of every human being of which no one
has the right to deprive him or her under any pretext, except in a case where a
person does something which deprives him or her of that right. It is mere
stupidity to leave its benefits to certain individuals and teams who monopolize
these while the masses provide the facilities and pay the expenses for the
establishment of public sports.";

// we don't want new lines in our preview
$text_only_spaces = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);

// truncates the text
$text_truncated = mb_substr($text_only_spaces, 0, mb_strpos($text_only_spaces, " ", 50));

// prevents last word truncation
$preview = trim(mb_substr($text_truncated, 0, mb_strrpos($text_truncated, " ")));
```

In this case, `$preview` will be `"Knowledge is a natural right of every human being"`.

Live code example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/25484a8b687d1f5ad93f62082b6379662a6b4713