# limit characters from <?php the_tags ?>

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a layout that have to show the tags horizontally. I want to be able to limit the amount of characters outputted.

Example - if I set the limit to 14 the following should happen.

Original: `Cats, Dogs, Rain`
New output: `Cats, Dogs, Ra..`

Please note that `<?php the_tags ?>` returns an array. It is everything returned I want limited to 14 characters.

**UPDATE**
In order to remove any confusion I have updated the post with a screenshot displaying why I want to set this limit. This should make it more clear what kind of solution I am searching for [alt text http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/2253/linit.png](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/2253/linit.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars) and a couple others.

Comment: Why don’t you adjust your layout and hide any overflowing contents with `overflow:hidden` and use some client side script to allow to view the hidden tags?

Comment: another possible duplicate [PHP - cut a string after X characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/php-cut-a-string-after-x-characters)

Answer (score 4):

`substr`

Check it out http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Something like this should work for you:

```
$tags = implode(', ', $the_tags)
echo substr($tags, 0, 14) . (strlen($tags) > 14) ? '..' : '';
```

`substr` will handle just showing 14 characters, then the last part appends the `..` when needed.

Comment: isnt substr just for strings? <?php the_tags() ?> returns an array

Comment: implode("",$the_tags) will give you a string, @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas, sorry that wasn't in the original post. I have updated my code to reflect this per @Shrapnel

Comment: @jason - it does not seem to work either way. I think I might need to edit my question to crush any misunderstanding

Comment: @Thomas, I know what you want. I think the confusion is more around your variables. What is the PHP variable name for the tags array?

Comment: The problem is `the_tags()` returns an array of HTML links, not just text!

Comment: In that case, I think the spec needs to change. My suggestion would be full tags up to a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function:

```
$string_new = substr($string, 0, 14);
echo $string_new;
```

You might want to also use the `strip_tags` function if you there are html tags coming in between your text.

Comment: @Jason McCreary: Missed that, +1 to you for adding that :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not very beautiful to cut the words in the middle.
This function will cut your phrase afrer the end of word, but not longer cpecified length.

```
function short($txt,$length)
{
    $txt = trim(strip_tags($txt));
    if(strlen($txt) > $length)
    {
        $txt = substr($txt,0,$length);
        $pos = strrpos($txt, " ");
        $txt = substr($txt,0,$pos);
        $txt .= "...";
    }
    return $txt;
}
```

But all answers before are right too.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with all these answers is that it has not been made clear that `the_tags()` returns an array of **HTML links**!

Running `substr(implode(', ', get_the_tags(), X)` might return something like;

```
<a href="/tag1/">Tag 1</a>, <a href="/tag2/">Tag 2</a>, <a href="/tag3
```

You'd be much better off opting for a CSS / front-end solution (as @Gumbo mentioned in the original comments).

That way, you'll still have your link juice and accessibility marked up, without ending up with something like;

```
<a href="/keyword-tag/">Keyword Tag</a>, <a href="/awesome-keyword/">Awes...</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should really rebuild the whole chain of `the_tags`, `get_the_tag_list` and `get_the_term_list`, but here's a solution in a single function.

It's based on WordPress' `get_the_term_list` function in `wp-includes/category-template.php`.

If no trim_length is specified, it hands off to `the_tags`. HTML entities were decoded so string counts would be accurate, then re-encoded into the output string.

I wasn't completely clear about the need for `$before`, `$sep` and `$after` in the last `the_tags` filter, so I deferred to what WordPress was already doing there.

```
function the_tags_trimmed( $before = null, $sep = ', ', $after = '', $trim_length = -1, $trim_characters = '...' ) {
    if ( $trim_length < 1 )
        return the_tags( $before, $sep, $after );

    if ( null === $before )
        $before = __('Tags: ');

    $tags = get_the_terms( 0, 'post_tag' );

    if ( empty( $tags ) )
        return false;

    $html_length = 0;
    $x = 0;

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $link = get_term_link( $tag, 'post_tag' );
        if ( is_wp_error( $link ) )
            return $link;
        $tag->name = html_entity_decode( $tag->name );
        if ( strlen($tag->name) + $html_length > $trim_length )
            $tag->name = substr( $tag->name, 0, $trim_length - $html_length) . $trim_characters;
        $tag_links[] = '<a href="' . $link . '" rel="tag">' . htmlentities($tag->name) . '</a>';
        $html_length += strlen($tag->name);
        if ( $x++ < count( $tags ) - 1 )
            $html_length += strlen( $sep );

        if ( $html_length >= $trim_length )
            break;
    }

    $tag_links = apply_filters( "term_links-post_tag", $tag_links );
    $tag_list = $before . join( $sep, $tag_links ) . $after;
    echo apply_filters( 'the_tags', $tag_list, $before, $sep, $after );
}
```

This was lightly tested and should accomplish the @Thomas was asking for.