# How to trim String based on Size php

Tags: php, string, truncate, string-length

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - cut a string after X characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/php-cut-a-string-after-x-characters)

Is there a way to cut or trim a String based on a Specific Size.

Let say we have "Lorem Ipsum dolor" and we want to cut that String to fit exactly the width of 20 Px and add "..." to the end of the String.

As far i tried this : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php but hard to get result as a newbie at PHP .

Comment: check this link .. it will solve your question 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/php-cut-a-string-after-x-characters

Comment: @TijoKVarghese i was searching for something like that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ye7hc8.aspx but just solved with that CSS Rule .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you shouldn't do this with PHP. Because Number of characters you can have inside 20px is depend on the Case of letters (Upper / Lower), language of the text, font, etc...

So you better try CSS.

Ex: `text-overflow: ellipsis;`