# How can I 'cut' a string to a determined length?

Tags: php, string

I need to receive a long string with lots of characters and 'cut' it to generate a string with the number of characters I determine, how can I do that?

Example:

```
$text = 'This is a long string with a lot of characters';
```

The `$text` string contains 46 characters in this example.

I need to generate a `$newText` string with only the 20 first characters, like this:

```
$newText = 'This is a long strin';
```

Comment: How exactly 'number of characters i determine' is decided?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - cut a string after X characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/php-cut-a-string-after-x-characters)

Comment: the number will be determined by me and will be a fixed number.. Thank you all guys, the substr did the job...

Comment: Surprised that none of the answers have mentioned that plain `substr` is not sufficient for multibyte strings ... You may need to consult [`mb_substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) and/or [`mb_strcut`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php)

Comment: @rdlowrey, what is multibyte string? is it something about special characters like UTF8? My string contains special characters like á ê ù, should I use mb_substr instead of just substr?

Comment: @LucasMatos The ASCII character set is very limited. You can't use it to display many international characters. Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newText = mb_substr($text, 0, 20);
```

Answer (score 5):

Not a problem, use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).  Using your variable names, to get the first 20 characters:

```
$newText = mb_substr($text, 0, 20, 'UTF-8');
```

This will get a substring of $text, starting at the beginning, stopping after 20 characters.

<edit>Updated to accomodate @rdlowrey suggestion and OP's character set.</edit>

Comment: You will do even better to set a variable with your cut string length instead of using a literal like 20.  It's good for maintenance, trust me - much easier to to change $string_lenght than find every applicable place you used 20 when you realize you need it to be 25.

Answer (score 3):

you mean like this?

```
$newText = substr($text, 0, 20);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [PHP string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php), and in particular, [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

> `string substr( string $string, int $start[, int $length])`
>
> Returns the portion of **string** specified by the **start** and **length** parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`strlen`](http://us.php.net/strlen) and [`substr`](http://us.php.net/substr).

```
<?php

$text = 'This is a long string with a lot of characters';
echo 'the $text string contains ' . strlen($text) . ' characters in this example.';
$newText = substr($text, 0, 20);

?>
```