# Combinate strlen(), str_replace(), substr()

Tags: php

I want to cut description string "$values['description']" after 13 character and add 3 dots after.

I found a solution here:

[PHP - cut a string after X characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/php-cut-a-string-after-x-characters)

```
$string = (strlen($string) > 13) ? substr($string,0,10).'...' : $string;
```

But it's a little bit complicated for me to combinate it with my code:

> 'desc' => str_replace(array("\t","\r", "\n"), '',
>   preg_replace('/(<.*?>)/', '',
>   htmlspecialchars_decode($values['description'])))

Comment: The question is, how I can combinate the two code into one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = str_replace(array("\t","\r", "\n"), '', preg_replace('/(<.*?>)/', '', htmlspecialchars_decode($values['description'])));

$string = (strlen($string) > 13) ? substr($string,0,10).'...' : $string;
```

Then add to your array?... leaves you with:

```
'desc' => $string
```

So the code should follow lines 1 and 2. Then $var= array('desc' => $string); or whatever your trying to do.

Comment: The first code snippet ($string = ...) is from that another question. My code is the " 'desc' => str_replace " <- I want to combine this code with that first one.

Comment: This has to be two commands. One is doing a replace. Once that is done we know something concrete about our string (i.e the size). Then using the logic you wanted applied to the string.

Comment: @Adrian read my last comment. We need to do this in two lines. Do the change before your code and then your code would look like this: 'desc' => $string. I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: If this worked as a solution for you please give it the check so others know who find this post at a later date. If not ask a question and I will respond to clarify more. Thanks!

Comment: So in your case. Add lines 1 and 2 right before $data[$key] = array(...). Then inside the $data[$key] = array( ... 'desc' => $string);