# Limit string to some number of characters

Tags: php

I`m trying to do the next task:
I have a string, for ex. "Product with a very long name so that it goes on to more than one line". I want to make next customization: if a number of charackters in the string (without spaces) will be more than 22, cut it on the last word, and add "...".

Comment: Cool, then do it. If you don't know how, post your current code and ask a question.

Comment: ^ The answer I gave in this question includes a much prettier CSS solution, which factors in the fact that llllllllll is nowhere near as "long" as WWWWWWWWWW.

Comment: I have read your solution with CSS. But, how does the browser know how many characters I want to left? And, will it be cross-browser solution?

Comment: But, as I understand, it will cut the string at the 50 character in your example. And I need the last word to be full

Comment: I think what you are looking for is some think like http://webwidetutor.com/php/substring/

Comment: A have already found answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17702942/2938377

Comment: The answer I found abowe is not quite right(( This algoritm cut the phrase after 22 symbols, including spaces. But I need to count 22 symbols in text without spaces, and then add '...' after the last full word. Please, has anyone some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  if(strlen($yourString) > 22)
    $rest = substr($yourString, 22,-1)."...";
  else
    $rest = $yourString;
  echo $rest;
?>
```

If you want that last word doesn't cut then,

```
<?php
$yourString = "bla blaaa bla blllla bla bla";
$out = "";
if(strlen($yourString) > 22) {
    while(strlen($yourString) > 22) {
        $pos = strrpos($yourString, " ");
        if($pos !== false && $pos <= 22) {
            $out = substr($yourString,0,$pos);
            break;
        } else {
            $yourString = substr($yourString,0,$pos);
            continue;
        }
    }
} else {
    $out = $yourString;
}
echo "Output String: ".$out;
?>
```

Comment: What if `$yourString` is already less than the max length?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes man..i forget that condition

Comment: In my case it returned:
ry long name so that it goes on to more than one lin...
And it is not correct.. Also, I need the last word to be full, not cut  as in this example

Comment: Do you want that last word don't cut?

Comment: Yes) I want to add "..." after the last full word, when the total number of characters (without spaces) will be less than 22. So, it may be 15 characters at the last word, when with the next word it will be summary 24 characters

Comment: Check the updated answer, If works I want u to optimize this answer. All the best

Comment: No, unfortunely it doesn`t work( It shows only b letter

Comment: @volodymyr3131 i had told you to optimize this. See the updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strlen($myString)>=22)
{
  $result = substr($myString, 0, 22)."...";
}
else
{
  $result = $myString;
}
```

Comment: A little comment wouldn't harm

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
<?php
$text = "A very long woooooooooooord.";
if(strlen($text) > 22 ) {
 echo substr($text, 1, 22)."..";
} else {
echo $text;
}

?>
```

Comment: The OP wants to **cut** a string after X characters, *not* span it into different lines.

Comment: @AmalMurali correct the post

Comment: What do you mean? Correct what?

Comment: No, it doesn`t work in the way I need