# How to get the first character of string in php

Tags: php

I need to get the first character of the given string. here i have a name in the session variable. i am passing the variable value to the `substr` to get the first character of the string. but i couldn't.

i want to get the first character of that string.

for example John doe.  i want to get the first character of the string `j`. how can i get it using php?

```
  <?php
      $username = $_SESSION['my_name'];
      $fstchar = substr($username, -1);
  ?>
```

Comment: try this `$fstchar = $username[0];`

Comment: $arr = str_split($username); echo $arr[0];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first n characters of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string)

Comment: `substr($username, -1);` gets the __last__ character of the string

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For the single-byte encoded (binary) strings:

```
substr($username, 0, 1);
// or 
$username[0] ?? null;
```

For the multi-byte encoded strings, such as UTF-8:

```
mb_substr($username, 0, 1);
```

Comment: If `$username` is an empty string, `$username[0]` produces a notice on PHP 7.x and a warning in PHP 8.x. [Example](https://3v4l.org/b00Jd)

Answer (score 22):

#### Three Solutions Sorted by Robustness

#### 1. `mb_substr`

It takes into consideration text encoding. Example:

```php
$first_character = mb_substr($str, 0, 1)
```

#### 2. `substr`

Example:

```php
$first_character = substr($str, 0, 1);
```

#### 3. Using brackets (`[]`)

Avoid as [it throws a notice in PHP 7.x and a warning in PHP 8.x if the string is empty](https://3v4l.org/b00Jd). Example:

```php
$first_character = $str[0];
```

Comment: [so?](https://3v4l.org/R954b)

Comment: What[??](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53610732/358906)

Answer (score 8):

In **PHP 8** if you just need to check if the first character of a given string is equal to something, you can do it like this:

```
if (str_starts_with($s, $characterToCheck)) {
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is with the Cyrillic alphabet, then you need to use it like this:

```php
mb_substr($username, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in PHP are array like, so simply

```
$username[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be seen as Char Arrays, and the way to access a position of an array is to use the [] operator, so there's no problem at all in using $str[0] (and I'm pretty sure is much faster than the substr method).

```
$fstchar = $username[0];
```

**faster than all method**

Answer (score 0):

I do not have too much experience in php, but this may help you: [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)