# how to show initials of first and Last name in laravel

Tags: laravel

Good Morning,
I am trying to show the Initials of First and Last name but no luck. Tried to use substr () but no luck
say Mr. abc xyz = should be shown as AX

thanks in advance,

```
substr ('Mr. abc xyz' ,  1 ); ?>"
```

Comment: Write your whole code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the first character of string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890810/how-to-get-the-first-character-of-string-in-php)

Comment: Don't fool yourself into thinking this is a simple problem.  Consider "Dr James Earl van Houten III" as an example.  You can throw out common prefixes and suffixes and grab the first letter of each word that remains.

Comment: Well, if some names are _prefixed_ with the person's title/profession(Mrs., Dr.,etc...), you would have to first know how to exclude them **before** tackling the issue at hand.  Is the person's title/profession stored separately in the database?

Comment: `substr` will clearly not work on its own. Have you tried anything else like combining it with an `explode` and writing some extra code to process the result?

Comment: This is the long way but it works. **1** ```$str = "Mr. abc xyz";```.  **2** ```$initials = explode(" ",$str);```.  **3** ```echo strtoupper(substr($initials[1], 0, 1)).strtoupper(substr($initials[2], 0, 1));```

Answer (score -2):

```
$str = 'Mr. abc xyz';
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
$arr = array_map(fn ($el) => rtrim($el, '.'), $arr);
echo $arr[1][0] . $arr[2][0];
```

but it is very bad example. If format will be change yu can get a very big problems)