# Take part of a huge text and print it (PHP)

Tags: php, text

I am trying to take part of a text in php.

I'm talking about, for example taking "Hello my name is..." from "Hello my name is John Doe, I am a computer engineer".

Is it possible to do this with php and how would I do this?

UPDATE: I want to return the first 20 characters and "..."

Comment: Do you know what the string is you want to extract?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, but it's going to depend on what you're looking for. Do you want the first four words? The first 16 characters? All the text before John?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/substr) to do accomplish this, and then append the `...` after taking the first twenty characters.

```
<?php

$input_string = "Hello my name is John Doe, I am a computer engineer.";

$text = substr($input_string, 0, 20) . '...';

print $text;
```

Which prints out:

```
Hello my name is Joh...
```