# Remove unwanted characters in given format

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have one string format in that remove unwanted characters and taken time format only my string is `10:02:in(user)` in that remove all the characters and taken 10:02 only how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first n characters of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using substr

```
$myStr = "10:02:in(user)";
echo $result = substr($myStr, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "10:02:in(user)";
echo substr($str, 0,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

### The explode() function is used to split a string.

> Syntax :

**explode(delimiter, string_name, limit)**

```
<?php
$str = "10:02:in(user)";
$new = explode(":", $str);
echo $new[0].":".$new[1];
?>
```