# Correct PHP syntax to truncate in PHP line

Tags: php, truncate

```
$modelProfileURL = $site_url.'profile/model/2/'.$rs_model[$i]['iModelId'].'/'.replace_content($rs_model[$i]['vFirstName']).'_'.replace_content($rs_model[$i]['vLastName']);
```

I need to truncate the first and last name to a max. of 25 characters.  But I can't find the correct way to edit the code listed above.  For example instead of the name being (for example: Mark Walker Smith Lewis Junior), it would only be Mark Walker Smith Lewis J. This is needed for design purposes.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first n characters of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

`$modelProfileURL = $site_url.'profile/model/2/'.$rs_model[$i]['iModelId'].'/'.replace_content(substr($rs_model[$i]['vFirstName'],0,25)).'_'.replace_content(substr($rs_model[$i]['vLastName'],0,25));`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  But this did not limit the number of characters in the name.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because ``substr()`` will definitely limit the string length when used as I described. Can you give an example of the contents of ``$modelProfileURL`` after this line is executed?