# how to split string in array from character to character in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

`20173400157080082` this is my string. I want this string to split in array from 4 to 7 and shows the result like this. `Array ( [0] => 400157 )` .I have tried string split but it split from starts of the string. But I want to split string into array by my given character. Thank You

Comment: So the resulting array should always have only 1 element, or why is does the middle part become index 0? Have a look at the [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first n characters of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161816/get-first-n-characters-of-a-string)

Comment: used this function `$string = substr($string,5,6);` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff8a1a345a5454f2299bc6caa77bedd5d401af43

Comment: Is it always 4 and 7? Sounds odd that you always want number starting with 4 and ending with 7.

Comment: @ShayanIshaq can you answer my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `substr` and `strpos`:

```
$a = '20173400157080082';
$result = [
    substr($a, strpos($a, '4'), strrpos($a, '7') - strpos($a, '4') + 1);
];
```

Or you can use `preg_match_all`, but this uses more resources:

```
$a = '20173400157080082';
preg_match_all('/[4](.*)+[7]/', $a, $match);
$result = $match[0];
```

Comment: @Shayan Ishaq ~ You should mark as correct if this solved the problem

Comment: Very large overhead for such a simple task

Comment: I appended answer @Andreas

Comment: Reversed you anwer. You should never use regex when simple string functions suffice.

Comment: thanks 
and what should I do when i want to break array not string
$a = array('20173400157080082');

Comment: you can convert value to string `$a = (string) $a[0];`

Comment: what is the use of needle in strpos ?

Comment: better strpos. it is much faster