# How to capture complete words using substr() in PHP, limit by word?

Tags: php, substring

When I use `substr($string,0,100)`, it gives first 100 characters. Sometimes it left the last word incomplete. That looks odd. Can I do limit by word rather than char?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what your definition of a "word" is? Are we talking only English words? Words in any language? Any sequence of letters, whether it is a real word or not? What about numbers? Punctuation? Other symbols? Is '<<<<<<<<' a word? etc...

Comment: Could the input text contain new line characters?

Comment: Try This Link, May help You
  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just count the words the resulting sting could still be very long as a single "word" might have 30 characters or more. I would suggest instead truncating the text to 100 characters, except if this causes a word to be truncated then you should also remove the truncated part of the word. This is covered by this related question:

**[How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-charac)**

**Using [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)**

```
$your_desired_width = 100;
if (strlen($string) > $your_desired_width)
{
    $string = wordwrap($string, 100);
    $i = strpos($string, "\n");
    if ($i) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $i);
    }
}
```

This is a modified versions of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-charac/79986#79986). if the input text could be very long you can add this line before the call to wordwrap to avoid wordwrap having to parse the entire text:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, 101);
```

**Using a regular expression** [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-charac/80066#80066)

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($string, 0, 100));
```

Comment: I would avoid using the wordwrap function as it will unnecessarily parse the entire string. The regular expression is the better of the two, IMO.

Comment: @konforce: I agree the regular expression solution is simple and flexible but some people aren't comfortable with regular expressions. I have proposed a new version of the wordwrap solution. Is it OK now?

Comment: the regular expression will accidentally remove the last word. I have added code to include a check. See the edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = explode('|', wordwrap($string, 100, '|');
print $a[0];
```

Comment: This fails if the character | accidentally occurs in $string. Better use chr(0) or something like it that will never occur in the $string.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Trim very long text to 120 characters. Add an ellipsis if the text is trimmed.
if(strlen($very_long_text) > 120) {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match("/^(.{1,120})[\s]/i", $very_long_text, $matches);
  $trimmed_text = $matches[0]. '...';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a single line code

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($string, 0, $length));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
<?php

        function cut_text($text, $len)
        {
                for ($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i)
                {
                        $c = $text[$len + $i];
                        if ($c == ' ' || $c == "\t" || $c == "\r" || $c == "\n" || $c == '-')
                                break;
                }

                if ($i == 10) $i = 0;

                return rtrim(substr($text, 0, $len + $i));
        }

        echo cut_text("Hello, World!", 3)."\n";
?>
```

Just start at some point ($len) and move forward a certain number of characters ($i) looking for a breaking character (e.g., whitespace). You could also look backward (-$i) or in both directions, depending on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution very similar to that of Scott Evernden, but also works if the character | accidentially occurs in the string:

```
$result = explode(chr(0), wordwrap($longtext, $len, chr(0)))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this simple one and it worked for me

```
<?php echo substr($content, 0, strpos($content, ' ', 200)); ?>
```