# Split string with read more by word count

Tags: php, string, split

I need a split string with 2 divs, by the first div with 20 words and last div with rest of words to make read more link with javascript.

At the moment I have only character count limit.

How can I do word splitting?

```
if ( $term && ! empty( $term->description ) ) {
            $first = substr($term->description, 0, 400);
            $rest = substr($term->description, 400);
            echo '<div class="term-description"><div class="first-letter">'.$first.'</div><div class="last-letter">'.$rest.'</div></div>';
        }
```

Comment: Maybe http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php can do the job

Comment: WordWrap split every words limit, not first limit and rest without split. Already tested.

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to an array, take the first 20 elements, [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back to a string, then take the rest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258557/limit-text-length-in-php-and-provide-read-more-link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display post excerpts, limited by word count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990007/display-post-excerpts-limited-by-word-count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does the trick:

```
<?php

function SplitStringToParts($sourceInput, &$first, &$rest, $countWordsInFirst = 20)
{
    $arr_exploded = explode(" ", $sourceInput);

    $arr_part1 = array_slice($arr_exploded, 0, $countWordsInFirst);
    $arr_part2 = array_slice($arr_exploded, $countWordsInFirst);

    $first = implode(" ",$arr_part1);
    $rest = implode(" ",$arr_part2);    
}

$str = "str1 str2 str3 str4 str5 str6 str7 str8 str9 str10 str11 str12 str13 str14 str15 str16 str17 str18 str19 str20 str21 str22 str23 str24";

SplitStringToParts($str,$first,$rest,20);

echo $first."<br>";
echo $rest."<br>";
```

Output is:

```
str1 str2 str3 str4 str5 str6 str7 str8 str9 str10 str11 str12 str13 str14 str15 str16 str17 str18 str19 str20
str21 str22 str23 str24
```

Use `SplitStringToParts` function. In your case you should call it as:
SplitStringToParts($term->description, $first, $rest, 20);

After it `$first, $rest` will keep your result

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:

```
<?php
// sentence teaser
// this function will cut the string by how many words you want
function word_teaser($string, $count){
  $original_string = $string;
  $words = explode(' ', $original_string);

  if (count($words) > $count){
   $words = array_slice($words, 0, $count);
   $string = implode(' ', $words);
  }

  return $string;
}

// sentence reveal teaser
// this function will get the remaining words
function word_teaser_end($string, $count){
 $words = explode(' ', $string);
 $words = array_slice($words, $count);
 $string = implode(' ', $words);
  return $string;
}
?>

$string = "We are BrightCherry web design, and we're going to show you how to write a function to crop a string  by a certain amount of words."

//this will echo the first 10 words of the string
echo word_teaser($string, 10);

$string = "We are BrightCherry web design, and we're going to show you how to write a function to crop a string by a certain amount of words."

//this will echo the words after the first 10 words
echo word_teaser_end($string, 10);
```