# How can I truncate a string in php without cutting off words?

Tags: php, string

Im looking for a soluting for the followting case.
I have a string

```
"This is a long string of words"
```

I want to use only the first few words, but if I just cut everything after 20th character, it will look like this:

```
"This is a long strin"
```

I can grab first 3 words

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', "This is a long string of words"), 0, 3));
```

But in some cases, 3 words are going to be too short "I I I".

How can I grab as many words as possible before 20th character?

Comment: What language are you using? C++, Java, C#, Php?

Comment: oh, I didnt mention, php

Comment: You can use regular expressions, or you can search for the space between words and use the split command to generate an array of words.

Comment: Try This Link, May help You...  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I give you an answer in PHP, have you considered the following CSS solution?

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

This will result in the text being cut off at the most appropriate place and an ellipsis `...` marking the cut-off.

If this is not the effect you're looking for, try this PHP:

```
$words = explode(" ",$input);
// if the first word is itself too long, like hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia‎
// then just cut that word off at 20 characters
if( strlen($words[0]) > 20) $output = substr($words[0],0,20);
else {
    $output = array_shift($words);
    while(strlen($output." ".$words[0]) <= 20) {
        $output .= " ".array_shift($words);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`echo array_shift(explode("\n", wordwrap($text, 20)));`

Documentation:

- [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array-shift)
- [`explode`](http://php.net/explode)
- [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/wordwrap)

Comment: Added some documentation links. +1 for using a function I'd forgotten about XD