# substr that won't cut out word with dynamic content

Tags: php, dynamic, substr

So, beginner designer here so any help given will be much appreciated and rewarded with internet cookies.

I have dynamic content for a news site that grabs its' stories from a daily updated database.  We are redesigning and it's always been a pet peev of mine that the whole teaser is put into the front page.  I'm condensing it down and modified a substr that was suggested to me.

```
<?php

        $position=200;

        $post = substr($row_News['teaser'],0,$position);

        echo $post;
        echo "...";
        ?>
```

It works absolutely perfect, expect for the fact it cuts a word in half.  Since the teasers are always changing, is this fixable or just something i have to live with if I use this substr?

Thanks always, cookies to be given out shortly.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233290/making-sure-php-substr-finishes-on-a-word-not-a-character/1233360#1233360

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/)

Comment: It is similar and probably a dup, but I have tried for about an hour with working with them, so I thought to just ask and see if I was missing something, which i was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do without using **regex** :

```
<?
$position=200;
$post = substr($row_News['teaser'],0,$position);
$post = substr($post, 0, strrpos($post, ' '));
echo $post."....";
?>
```

Reference : [Making sure PHP substr finishes on a word not a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233290/making-sure-php-substr-finishes-on-a-word-not-a-character/1233360#1233360)

Comment: Internet cookies for all, but two for you!  Tried them all and modified as needed to get to work, and this one is what i was most looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question is almost the same as [Making sure PHP substr finishes on a word not a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233290/making-sure-php-substr-finishes-on-a-word-not-a-character)

Example:

```
$post = $row_News['teaser'];
if (preg_match('/^.{1,260}\b/s', $row_News['teaser'], $match))
{
    $post=$match[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/wordwrap) function

```
$string_limit = 200;
$delimiter = "...";
if(strlen($row_News['teaser']) > $string_limit){

    // If string is bigger than limit
    $intact = wordwrap($row_News['teaser'], $string_limit);
    $intact_array = explode("\n", $intact);
    $str = $intact_array[0] . $delimiter;
}
else{

    // else string will be as it is
    $str = $row_News['teaser'];
}
```