# Extracting substring ending with word not working in PHP

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, substr

I am trying to extract a substring from a string in PHP. The extracted substring should end with a word. I tried with the following code and I'm not getting any output.

```
if (strlen($userresult->aboutme) > 20)    // value of $userresult->aboutme is 'Very cool and friendly'
{   
   $description=substr($userresult->aboutme, 0, strpos($userresult->aboutme, ' ', 20));
} 
else 
{
    $description=$userresult->aboutme;
}
echo $description;     // not outputting any result
```

I want the substring to be end up with a word. Here, I want output as `Very cool and friendly` instead of `Very cool and friend` which is the output when we try with `substr($userresult->aboutme, 0, 20);`. What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `strpos()` call returns `false`. That is why the `substr()` returns an empty string.

Comment: I believe your examples are not correct with what you want

Comment: Try This Link, May help You...  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're useing [strpos()](https://www.php.net/strpos), which looks from the start of a string. You want [`strRpos()`](https://www.php.net/strrpos) (r=reverse):

```
$description=substr($userresult->aboutme, 0, strrpos($userresult->aboutme, ' '));
```

You don't want to use the offset for the `strpos()`, because it might work in this situation, but if the first few words are shorter/longer, it no longer works.

Comment: `Very cool and friendly dude!` what about this string as long? Output `Very cool and friendly`

Answer (score 0):

```
// split in words
$words = explode(' ', $userresult->aboutme);
// remove the last word
array_pop($words);
// combine again
echo implode(' ', $words);
```

This is not respecting any other seperator as comma or dot. But you are not doing that either.

Comment: Not going to downvote because it's another perspective at a problem, but you should not do this. **NEVER** use array functions for simple string functions. String functions are (almost) always faster and less resource intensive

Comment: And why is that, exactly?

Comment: Yeah @Martijn you got my curious, here. Is that this much of a performance issue?

Comment: Arrays are slow, string functions are very fast. You do the math :p

Comment: I did a small benchmark: Your code 100.000x takes 1.5sec, my code 100.000x takes 0.9sec. The string function is 40% faster.

Comment: Nice info, thx @Martijn! But it still is a valid answer unless the page is actually called more than 10.000 times

Comment: IMO it a working answer, not a valid answer, but we could argue about tthat all day :p In this stand-alone situation this doesnt matter, but but if you apply this tactic to your whole site, you're gonna notice 40% ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 if (strlen($userresult->aboutme) > 15)    // value of $userresult->aboutme is 'Very cool and friendly'
  {   
   $description=substr($userresult->aboutme, 0, strrpos($userresult->aboutme, ' '));
  } 
  else 
  {
   $description=$userresult->aboutme;
   }

  echo $description;
```