# PHP Cut String On Character Limit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, faker, htmlpurifier

I'm creating a **Blog** that uses a **Faker** Factory to generate **Demo Data**. I have a **Post Model** which is generated that has a body field which contains randomly generated **HTML** as well as a **text field** which is created by **stripping** the tags from the body and **limiting** the data received to **512 characters**. **str_limit** works fine it is just that I need to cut the **text** off on a word while keeping it in the 512 **limit**.

**This is my factory:**

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Provar\Forum\Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {

   $randomHTML = Purifier::clean($faker->randomHtml(2,3));

   $trimedHTML = strip_tags($randomHTML);

   return [
      'body' => $randomHTML,
      'text' => str_limit($trimedHTML, 509, '...')
   ];

});
```

Any help is appreciated. <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try with something like this, but this might cut the last word

```php
substr($trimedHTML, 0, 512) . '...'
```

If you don't want the last word cut, you might do something like this, but will not give you exactly 512 characters always, cause next word might be to big...

```php
$text=$trimedHTML;
if (preg_match('/^.{1,512}\b/s', $trimedHTML, $match))
{
    $text=$match[0] . ( strlen($match[0]) < strlen($trimedHTML) ? "..." : "" );
}
```

And use the $text, variable instead of `str_limit($trimedHTML, 509, '...')`

This code is literally the same as the one in this answer: 
[Making sure PHP substr finishes on a word not a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233290/making-sure-php-substr-finishes-on-a-word-not-a-character)
Though this might be considered "another question" so...

Comment: I don't want the last word cut.

Comment: Now it is cutting off on the words thank you but it adds the ellipses regardless if it has reached the limit or not.

Comment: `if (preg_match('/^.{1,509}\b/s', $trimedHTML, $match)) {
        $text=$match[0];
        if(strlen($text) < 509) {
            $text += '...';
          }
      }`

Comment: yeah probably less expensive in computing terms since you compare directly too your limit.