# PHP code for Substr - Making It Stop After A Word?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shorten String in PHP (full words only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972010/shorten-string-in-php-full-words-only)

Below substr which iam using . Which echo first 38 characters from my database. This code breaking the word which is at end .

```
<?php echo substr(ucfirst($row['metadesc']),0,38); ?>...
```

which output like this.

```
news for today was null try tomo
```

how to stop the string after 38 characters after the end of word.

output should be like this

```
news for today was null try tomorrow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function TrimString($String, $Length)
{
    if(strlen($String) > $Length)
    {
        $Temp[0] = substr($String, 0, $Length);
        $Temp[1] = substr($String, $Length);
        $SpacePos = strpos($Temp[1], ' ');
        if($SpacePos !== FALSE)
        {
            return $Temp[0].substr($Temp[1], 0, $SpacePos);
        }
    }
    return $String;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function substrword($str, $begin, $length) 
{
    if (($begin + $length) < strlen($str)) {    
            return substr($str, $begin, $length).current(explode(' ', substr($str, $length))).'...';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
preg_match('/^(.{1,38})\b/u', $string, $matches);
```

Your string will be:

```
$matches[1]
```