# Shorten a text string in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to trim a text string in PHP so it has a certain number of characters? For instance, if I had the string:

`$string = "this is a string";`

How could I trim it to say:

`$newstring = "this is";`

This is what I have so far, using `chunk_split()`, but it isn't working. Can anyone improve on my method?

```
function trimtext($text)
{
$newtext = chunk_split($text,15);
return $newtext;
}
```

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972010/shorten-string-in-php-full-words-only?rq=1) question, but I don't really understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15705059/

Comment: no, I am not using regex.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't a regex solution :)

Comment: Imulsion, the answer there is way better than those below. The answers below will cut off the word and you may get something like `this is a str` which isn't what you want. Therefor the answer in the link I provided is suited, it won't cut off a string in the middle, just remove the `$theExcerpt .= '...';` part.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if (strlen($yourString) > 15) // if you want...
{
    $maxLength = 14;
    $yourString = substr($yourString, 0, $maxLength);
}
```

will do the job.

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: Can you explain the second parameter please?

Comment: @imulsion: second parameter is the length where to "cut" your string)

Comment: Thank you! Accepting when it lets me. Stupid ten minute waiting period

Answer (score 7):

substr cuts words in half. Also if word contains UTF8 characters, it misbehaves. So it would be better to use mb_substr:

`$string = mb_substr('word word word word', 0, 10, 'utf8').'...';`

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say the reason for this but think about what you want to achieve. Here is a function for shorten a string word by word with or without adding ellipses at the end:

```
function limitStrlen($input, $length, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true) {
    //strip tags, if desired
    if ($strip_html) {
        $input = strip_tags($input);
    }

    //no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
    if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
        return $input;
    }

    //find last space within length
    $last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
    if($last_space !== false) {
        $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);
    } else {
        $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $length);
    }
    //add ellipses (...)
    if ($ellipses) {
        $trimmed_text .= '...';
    }

    return $trimmed_text;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function trimtext($text, $start, $len)
{
    return substr($text, $start, $len);
}
```

---

You can call the function like this:

```
$string = trimtext("this is a string", 0, 10);
```

Would return:

`This is a`

Answer (score 3):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr) let's you take a portion of string consisting of exactly as much characters as you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
substr()
```

function to get substring

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a string with a certain number of characters you can use substr, i.e.

```
$newtext = substr($string,0,$length);
```

where $length is the given length of the new string.

Answer (score 1):

My function has some length to it, but I like to use it. I convert the string int to a Array.

```
function truncate($text, $limit){
    //Set Up
    $array = [];
    $count = -1;
    //Turning String into an Array
    $split_text = explode(" ", $text);
    //Loop for the length of words you want
    while($count < $limit - 1){
      $count++;
      $array[] = $split_text[$count];
    }
    //Converting Array back into a String
    $text = implode(" ", $array);

    return $text." ...";

  }
```

Or if the text is coming from an editor and you want to strip out the HTML tags.

```
function truncate($text, $limit){
    //Set Up
    $array = [];
    $count = -1;
    $text = filter_var($text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //Turning String into an Array
    $split_text = preg_split('/\s+/', $text);
    //Loop for the length of words you want
    while($count < $limit){
      $count++;
      $array[] = $split_text[$count];
    }

    //Converting Array back into a String
    $text = implode(" ", $array);

    return $text." ...";

  }
```

Comment: if the size of $split_text is less than $limit it must return $text as is otherwise it will throw warnings

Answer (score 0):

If you want an abstract for the first 10 words  (you can use html in $text, before script there is strip_tags)
use this code:

```
preg_match('/^([^.!?\s]*[\.!?\s]+){0,10}/', strip_tags($text), $abstract);
echo $abstract[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

With elipsis (...) only if longer - and taking care of special language-specific characters:

```
mb_strlen($text,'UTF-8') > 60 ? mb_substr($text, 0, 60,'UTF-8') . "…" : $text;
```