# how i can display only 2 phrase from sql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have this and i want to show only 2 line of each article from sql then i would be able to show more button in my

$pdoStat= $tableCompetence -> prepare('SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY `article`.`dateArticle` DESC limit 5');

```
 <?php foreach ($Compe as $temo):?>
        <li class="slide">
            <div class="quoteContainer">
                <p class="quote-phrase"><span class="quote-marks">"</span> <?= $temo['titreArticle']?><br><span class="quote-marks"></span>
                    <?= $temo['textArticle']?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="authorContainer">
                <p class="quote-author"> <?= $temo['dateArticle']?></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: you mean literaly 2 lines of the 'textArticle' or two articles?

Comment: i mean 2 lines of 'textArticle'

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278756/shorten-a-text-string-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: it don't work :(

Comment: $yourString=$temo['textArticle'];
                if (strlen($temo['textArticle']) > 15) // if you want...
                {
                $maxLength = 14;
                $yourString = substr($yourString, 0, $maxLength);
                }
                ?>

Comment: As  jeff suggested use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like `$quotePharse = substr($temo['textArtical'],0,$whereyouwantocut) .`

Comment: <?= substr($temo['textArticle'],0,300)?> i just did like this and it works perfectly