# How to get a get_the_content word limit

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a get_the_content() Wordpress code as you can see below. I want to force the code to do the following:

- Don't display empty tags as nbsp; (works now)
- Display only a limited amount of words (don't know how)

I added this code to my home.php:

```
<?php 
$content = get_the_content('Read more');
$content = str_replace('&nbsp;'," ", get_the_content());
$content = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $content );
echo $content; 
?>
```

It works, but i want to display only a limited amount of words now. All the solutions as $char_limit and wp_trim_words() are not the solutions i am looking for, because they are mess up the blog posts.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this handy utility function for restricting word count with respect to words described in here [Get first 100 characters from string, respecting full words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972010/get-first-100-characters-from-string-respecting-full-words)

```
function truncate($text, $length) {
   $length = abs((int)$length);
   if(strlen($text) > $length) {
      $text = preg_replace("/^(.{1,$length})(\s.*|$)/s", '\\1...', $text);
   }
   return(str_replace('&nbsp;'," ", $text));
}
```

Pass the values like

```
$content = get_the_content('Read more');
print_r(truncate($content, 180));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function limitText($text, $limit)
{
    $count = strlen($text);
    if ($count >= $limit) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, strrpos(substr($text, 0, $limit), ' ')) . '...';

        return $text;
    } else {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

And the echo

```
 <?= limitText(get_the_content(), 30); ?>
```