# How to prevent mb_substr cutting words in half in php

Tags: php, laravel

At the moment whenever there are more than 300 characters the string stops, halfway through a word as well, and begins on a new line.

I want it to be able to continue on the same line where it left off but it just starts on a new line.

Example of how it breaks

```
This will break at 300 charac
ters
```

Want to achieve

```
This will break at 300 characters
```

My code

```
@if (strlen($server->description) >= 300) 
   {!! nl2br(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($server->description), 0, 300)) !!}
     <div class="collapse" id="collapse{{$server->id}}">
          {!! nl2br(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($server->description), 300)) !!}
     </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first 100 characters from string, respecting full words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972010/get-first-100-characters-from-string-respecting-full-words)